# Can I transpose one long column into multiple rows, a new row for every blank cell (or any delimitter)?

Tags: excel, vba, formula

I have a gigantic Word list, that I've converted to .txt and imported into Excel. When I import it just goes into one big column, every line in a new cell down the column. The info is like this:

Name: Xyz ltd
Date: 1/1/1990
Country: Ireland
etc: etc

Name: abc ltd
Date: 1/1/2990
Country: Japan
etc: etc
etc:etc

Name: jfj ltd
Date: etc

They don't neccesarily all have the same amount of cells before a blank space is present but if needs be I can make that so. I can also make the blank cells some sort of delimiter like a % sign.

I want to convert it to this (i've placed a comma where a new cell in the row should be):

Name: Xyz ltd, Date: 1/1/1990, Country: Ireland, etc: etc
Name: abc ltd, Date: 1/1/2990, Country: Japan, etc: etc etc:etc
Name: jfj ltd, Date: etc, etc

Simple transposing just puts it all in one long row instead of down one long column.

Any ideas? Thank you (btw I'm talking tens of thousands of lines across different Word docs so doing this manually is out of the question really)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub QuickandDirty()
Dim r As Range  'cell to read
Dim t As Range  'cell to write
Set r = Range("A1")
Set t = Range("B1")
Do Until r.Row > r.Parent.UsedRange.Rows.Count
   t.Value = r.Text  'copy text
   Set r = r.Offset(1, 0) 'move r down
   Set t = t.Offset(0, 1) 'move t across
   If r = "" Or r = " " Then 'r is blank or has a space
      Set r = r.Offset(1, 0) 'move down 1 more
      Set t = Cells(t.Row + 1, 2) 'reset t to column b, next row
   End If
Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Wouldn't this `If r = "" Or r = " " Then ` split this "Name: Xyz ltd" in two rows?

Comment: no because r is the whole cell so only triggers if the cell contains either nothing or just a space without any other chars